# Create and manage Google groups

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-iam, google-identity, google-groups

I learned that group management is done via "Google Workspace" and requires specific privileges that are outside of the scope of GCP roles.

I'm looking for a simple way to **directly** (without impersonations) use a GCP service account in order to run a `gcloud` command to manage groups as that service account e.g :

```
gcloud identity groups memberships add --group-email="my@group.com" --member-email="my@user.com"

# OR

gcloud identity groups create my@group.com --organization="example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

See this,   > https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/08/service-accounts-in-google-groups-beta.html

Service accounts can now have direct access to Groups APIs without needing domain-wide delegation and admin impersonation. This means you can:
Assign an admin role to a service account using the Admin SDK roles API and Admin console Roles page.
Use a service account with an admin role to manage groups at a customer level via the Admin SDK Groups API and the Cloud Identity Groups API.
Use a service account with group owner or manager role (non-admin) to manage groups via the Cloud Identity Groups API.
See accurate audit logs with service accounts as the actor.